# How to change primary-color of webpack for laravel?

Tags: laravel-backpack

A customer, sigh, asked to change buttons to standard 'boostrap blue' color.

Could you point me to a guide on which file change and how to recompile theme?

Or tell me if there is a way to override compiled theme without do bad things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this section in the Backpack 4.2 docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.2-dev/base-how-to#change-the-colors) to do that. The same also works for Backpack 4.1.

In short, in your `config/backpack/base.php`, under `styles` you should stop using the standard bundle file and use the blue bundle instead:

```
'styles' => [
-        'packages/backpack/base/css/bundle.css',
+        'packages/backpack/base/css/blue-bundle.css',
```

Make sure you're running Backpack 4.1.57+ for that `blue-bundle.css` file to exist. If it still doesn't, re-publish the assets using `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\CRUD\BackpackServiceProvider" --tag=public --force`

Comment: We will follow the manual way, as new doc states, as soon as we upgrade backpack again (one or two weeks)